# Accidently read resistance on live wires

Tags: multimeter

I have accidently taken readings of resistance on my digital multimeter on live mains and now the resistance function on my meter is not working. But i'm still able to use other functions in it. Is there a possible fix for it? I know that the multimeter is fused, why did'nt the fuse go off?

Comment: ... Because the fuse isn't part of the resistance measurement circuit.

Comment: Is there a fix ?

Comment: Nope. If your meter doesn't recover on its own then it's fried.

Comment: My DVM has two fuses. One for Volts-Amps, and a another for Ohms measurement circuit. I did blow that Ohms fuse once. So I learned not to do that. But I've kept extra fuses in the case ever since!

Comment: I'm not a big fan of fuses on the resistance path. They have their own internal resistance which will skew the results. Better to have a DMM with robust resistance measurement instead.

Comment: Probably it can be used as a volt-ammeter

Comment: What you will find reading some of these answers is that each meter is different.  Some can take the abuse, some have fuses, some can be repaired, and some...just become a keepsake of a learning experience.

Answer (score 5):

There are two kinds of mulimeters. Good ones and ones that better work as a drink coaster.

A good meter is designed to survive connecting the resistance function to mains (live wiring). Bad meters usually do not survive.

The fuse in the meter is only designed to protect the current measurement function. Once the meter is damaged there is usually very little or nothing you can do to fix it.

Comment: I think my multimeter falls under the el-chepo kind of category. But I have managed to find the schematic if any one could show me if it is possible to trouble shoot it [link](http://imgur.com/a/Gn6Hb)

Answer (score 0):

Those harbor freight ones usually fail catastrophically(the big IC blob blows internally).  Older through-hole (component) meters usually can be repaired by replacing a resistor or two.  Good ones will blow fuse and sacrifice its life for the error you made. (Don't be measuring ohms on a live circuit and only measure amps when the leads are in 10 or 5 amp sockets, then immediately put leads back where they belong.)

The old saying measure twice and cut once applies here when using a MM.

Comment: "*...  measure twice and cut once applies here ...*" That's a rathe r unfortunate choice of metaphor. How about, "*Check twice and measure once ...*" Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: my bad.. thanks for the welcome.  nice website and I like the "answer only" format.  Just bare bones information that we need to be up and running again  --  fantastic !!!!!!